# Entity Framework 4 and generating POCO classes using Poco entity generator

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-generation, entity, poco

I generate my poco classes by updating my edmx file from the database and run the standard POCO entity generator template.

I wonder if any of you has written a T4 template that generate Poco classes that contain a max field length for each string field?

For example, if I have a table with a column named Title that is a varchar(100) column, I would like to generate 2 fields. One That is the standard "string Title" property and the related max length field property like "int? TitleMaxLength"

Do any of you have an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Entity Framework Power Tools

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d